# Why can't you use #1 and #2 in Select

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

This doesn't work in Mathematica. I need it to find the number of instances for which the jump between the elements of the list is positive.

Here's the formula which seems intuitive for me : `Length[Select[{-2, 1, 2, 4}, #1 < #2 &]]`

Why doesn't this work and what should I use instead?

We're not allowed to use `For`, `While`, `Do` or `Table` command...

Comment: That `Select` is going to pass one thing at a time to your function so there is no `#2` to use. Can you think of any way to break the list into a list of pairs of items? Those pairs would overlap so that you would get every possible adjacent pair. Is that enough of a hint? If not then can you edit your post to describe any possible related ideas from class that were shown to you before the homework question?

Comment: Random comment - there is also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, using a similar select form

```
Length@Select[Partition[{-2, 1, 2, 4}, 2, 1], #[[1]] < #[[2]] &]
```

> 3

Also

```
Count[#1 < #2 & @@@ Partition[{-2, 1, 2, 4}, 2, 1], True]
```

and

```
Count[Differences@{-2, 1, 2, 4}, _?(# > 0 &)]
```